# Optional parameters in SQL UDF without DEFAULT keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I am looking for a solution, how to create SQL UDF with optional params.

Pseudocode for function where Param1 is necessary and Param2 may be filled (but not needed):

```
dbo.myFnc(Param1 int [, Param2 int])
```

Is there a way to create thislike function? For existing built-in sample watch the [STR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)

```
STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] )
```

Comment: No with a UDF, but yes with a SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define default parameters in the create statement (= default):

```
--Transact-SQL Inline Table-Valued Function Syntax 
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name 
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ = default ] [ READONLY ] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS TABLE
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    RETURN [ ( ] select_stmt [ ) ]
[ ; ]
```

[Source MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/ms186755.aspx)

So you can do something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myFnc(
 @param1 int, -- necessary
 @param2 int = 5 -- 5 as default
)
```

But as shree.pat18 said you need to call the optional function parameter with the "default".
Like:

```
dbo.myFnc(5, default)
```

Comment: yes, but I have to rewrite whole project writing _default_... So without _default_ in UDF impossible?

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass all arguments to functions, unlike stored procedures. You can use the `default` keyword to indicate that default value is to be used for the parameter, rather than a user-specified value.

So you can create your function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myFnc
(
 @param1 int,
 @param2 int)

...
```

and then call the function like this:

```
dbo.myFnc(Param1, default)
```

Comment: yes, I know this. But in this case I have to fill "default" key word :(

Comment: @MartinProcházka: You could always use a stored procedure instead, in which case explicitly requesting the default is not necessary.

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem with UDF. Stored procedures would be a good idea to overcome this, but is there a real issue that you are facing with this workaround i.e. apart from having to type out default :)?

Comment: @shree.pat18: Finding the best way :) Not only for this job, but also for upcomming ones...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which SQL you are referring to, but is it possible to overload the UDF?

```
dbo.myFnc(Param1 int )

dbo.myFnc(Param1 int , Param2 int)
```

some sql allows  it some doesn't. If yours doesn't, maybe you could try something the could handle null as input

```
create function func
(
    @in1 int,
    @in2 int
)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @count int

    select @count = count(*)
    from table
    where
        field1 = isnull(@in1, field1)
        and field2 = isnull(@in2, field2)

    return @count
end
go
```

so you could do something like

```
select func(null,9)
```

Comment: Thanx for good kick ;) But my problem is, that one UDF is used through a big part of the project. Now we need to extend the UDF functionality (close to "overloading"). We cannot use same name for two different UDFs (_fnc(p1)_ and _fnc(p1,p2)_). It is not allowed. In the best way, we do not want to rewrite whole project by filling _default_ key word or something else.

Comment: Exactly _fnc(p1)_ and _fnc(p2)_ cannot be declared separately, so I am looking for solution which creates one UDF woth optional params. So it looks impossible. Maybe rewrite it to SP...?

Comment: will it be possible to use a wrapper approach? funcExtended(param1, param2) { @temp=select func(param1); select @result=result from table where field1=@temp and field2=param2; }

Comment: sure, wrapper possible, but asked directly for "clear" optional param. Understanding as a param, that need not to be filled (also no default key word)

Comment: i got nothing then XD good luck with your quest

Comment: Thanx a lot, Jacky Cheng, for your idea